# HTTP only for JWT?

Tags: reactjs, cookies, jwt, jsx

Should my JWT be HTTPOnly? I currently create them like this:

```
const token = jwt.sign(user, config.secret, {
                     expiresIn: 604800 // 1 week
                 });
    new Cookies(req,res).set('access_token',token,{
        httpOnly: false,
        secure: false      // for your production environment
    });
```

And get them like this using universal-cookie:

```
const cookies = new Cookies();
var token = cookies.get('access_token');
```

Is this secure? If not or there is another reason not to do it this way how should I do it? If the JWT cookie is http only then the get request comes back as undefined.

Thanks, Ed.

Comment: I usually return the token in the JSON response. Then the clients should send the token on every request using the headers. This approach allows me to effectively communicate webapps as well as native apps using the same API ;)

Comment: Thanks, you wouldn't know of any articles/tutorials that would show me how to do that would you? Thanks  ;)

Comment: Who is verifying the access token? In case it's on your side, use httpOnly:false and https://github.com/kjur/jsrsasign/wiki/Tutorial-for-JWS-verification. If it's not your part of the deal and token is verfied by the backend, use httpOnly:true. In both cases use secure:true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [JWT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519) specification  says that:

> JSON Web Token (JWT) is a compact claims representation format
> intended for space constrained environments such as HTTP Authorization
> headers and URI query parameters.

So it states that it is **intended** for HTTP Authorization headers and URI query parameters. You can use it as a cookie as the specification doesn't prohibit it. I can imaging use cases where it's reasonable to use JWT token as a cookie and specifically as HttpOnly. Now the question about making it HttpOnly depends on the following:

1. Do you need to access it from the client code (JavaScript)?
2. Is there any impact of compromising the token to a potential attacker?

If you don't need to access it from the client code or there is an impact of disclosing the token then make it HttpOnly.